# Переклад з російської "посыл статьи"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Англійською цей вираз можна було б перекласти як key message of the article

Оновлення:
Розгорнуте тлумачення терміну "посыл" російською за допомогою вислову "отправная точка в рассуждениях" підштовхнуло мене до такого варіанту перекладу - "теза".

Comment: як вам *основне / головне / ключове [послання](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)* статті? Тут стаття як посланець - несе послання.

Comment: ні, слово "послання" не можна вжити в значенні "основна думка", "теза"

http://sum.in.ua/s/poslannja

Comment: я мав на увазі, що це слово / словосполучення відповідає на ваше на запитання. Я не мав на увазі, що це синонім до *основна думка* чи *теза*.

Answer (score 4):

**Основна/головна думка статті** або просто **думка статті**.

- [Тема й основна думка тексту](http://shkolyar.in.ua/tema)

> Тема тексту – це його зміст, то, про що (або про кого) в ньому йдеться. **Головна думка** тексту – те, заради чого його було створено (чого він навчає, до чого закликає, від чого
> застерігає)
>
> Тему тексту автор розкриває поступово: він переходить від однієї частини теми до іншої.

- [Тема і основна думка тексту](http://moodle.mdu.in.ua/mod/book/view.php?id=7865)

> Тема тексту — коло предметів чи явищ, розглянутих у тексті, це те, про
> що оповідає текст. Мікротема — частина загальної теми. У тексті може
> бути більше чи менше мікротем, залежно від складності тексту.
>
> **Основна думка** — ідея тексту, висвітленню якої підпорядковані всі
> складники тексту.

- [Тема  й  основна  думка  висловлювання. Тема  й  мікротема](https://disted.edu.vn.ua/courses/learn/608)

> ТЕКСТ - це  група речень чи одне речення, об'єднаних темою та **основною думкою**, мають певну змістову та структурну завершеність.

Answer (score 1):

Це не зовсім те саме, але в деяких випадках підійде ***напрямок думки/думок автора***, ***напрямок думки/думок у тексті***. Приклади:

> Спільним знаменником, що задає **напрямок думки обох мислителів**, у цьому випадку є неокантіанство й часто пряма залежність думок Б. Кістяківського від поглядів Г. Риккерта. // В'ячеслав Артюх, Тяглість історії й історія тяглості, 2010.
>
> Оскільки **основний напрямок думки** в драмі можна характеризувати як пантеїстичний, значна увага приділяється красі природи, а тому арії наповнені пейзажною лірикою. // Ярослав Щербаков, Буддійські мотиви в драмі доби Юань (1271–1368), 2015.
>
> Теми у творчості М. Шагала. <…> А. Тема будинків. <…> Б. Тема тварин. <…> В. Людська постать. Подібний **напрямок думки** підтримує тема людської постаті. // Дебора Фогель, Теми і форми в мистецтві Марка Шагала. Начерк естетичної критики, 1929 (переклад з польської: Дана Пінчевська, 2018).